# Polygon (MATIC) is a Coin or Token?

Tags: tokens, polygon, layer-2

If polygon is a Layer-2 solution is built upon Ethereum then why it is listed as Coin in coinmarketcap intead of as Token ?

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking Polygon - it is a native asset, which is used to pay fees, and is treated like Ether on Ethereum, meaning it is a coin.
But as far as it was initially launched as an ERC20 token on Ethereum network,
most likely it's the reason why Matic's treated not like a wrapped token of a native coin, but a token.